# Getting relevant quarter dates for Public Stocks using R

Tags: r, stock

Trying to generate a function that determines the previous 3 Relevant Quarterly dates given the Current Day. Basically I am checking what quarter I am in then grabbing the three previous Quarters which can get complicated if it is currently Q2 and I need Q3 2021, Q4 2021, and Q1 2022. Why does my function currently return NA for all values I am confused! Please give me suggestions or solutions thanks you!

```
# set dates
first.date <- Sys.Date() - 60
last.date <- Sys.Date()
current.year <- format(last.date, format ="%Y")

quarters <- quarter(first.date)
prev.year <- as.numeric(current.year) - 1

quart.df <- data.frame(month = c(3, 6, 9, 12),
                       day = c(31, 30, 30, 31))

getQs <- function(date.curr){
  current.year <- format(date.curr, format ="%Y")
  prev.year <- as.numeric(current.year) - 1
  prev.year <- str(prev.year)
  q <- quarter(date.curr)
  day <- 
  rel.qs <- c()
  if (q == 1){
    rel.qs[1] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(prev.year,month[2],day[2])), "%Y-%m-%d")
    rel.qs[2] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(prev.year,month[3],day[3])), "%Y-%m-%d")
    rel.qs[3] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(prev.year,month[4],day[4])), "%Y-%m-%d")
  }
  if (q == 2){
    rel.qs[1] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(prev.year,month[3],day[3])), "%Y-%m-%d")
    rel.qs[2] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(prev.year,month[4],day[4])), "%Y-%m-%d")
    rel.qs[3] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(current.year,month[1],day[1])), "%Y-%m-%d")
  }
  if (q == 3){
    rel.qs[1] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(prev.year,month[4],day[4])), "%Y-%m-%d")
    rel.qs[2] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(current.year,month[1],day[1])), "%Y-%m-%d")
    rel.qs[3] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(current.year,month[2],day[2])), "%Y-%m-%d")
  }
  else{
    rel.qs[1] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(current.year,month[1],day[1])), "%Y-%m-%d")
    rel.qs[2] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(current.year,month[2],day[2])), "%Y-%m-%d")
    rel.qs[3] <- as.Date(with(quart.df, paste(current.year,month[3],day[3])), "%Y-%m-%d")
  }
  return(rel.qs)
}

getQs(last.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this to get the prior quarters?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(clock)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:clock':
#> 
#>     as_date
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

today <- date_today(Sys.timezone())
  
# Last 3 quarters
ceiling_date(today - months(3), "quarter") - 1
#> [1] "2022-03-31"
ceiling_date(today - months(6), "quarter") - 1
#> [1] "2021-12-31"
ceiling_date(today - months(9), "quarter") - 1
#> [1] "2021-09-30"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes but I am more interested in getting a returned list of the Exact dates so for Q1 2022 I would need the end of the quarter date so March 31st 2022, for Q4 2021 : December 31st, 2021, and for Q3 2021: September 30, 2021. I need to use that date list to call a dictionary with the associated stock price to each date to get the Quarterly end Price of a stock.

Comment: Updated with the dates

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem by using the function ceiling_date() from the lubridate package. This would be my suggestion:

```
CurrentDate <- Sys.Date()

getQs <- function(StartDate, QuartersBack){
  
  vec.Dates <- vector(length = QuartersBack)
  class(vec.Dates) <- "Date"
  
  for (i in c(1:QuartersBack)) {
    vec.Dates[i] <- lubridate::ceiling_date(StartDate %m-% months(3*i), "quarter") - 1
  }
  
  vec.Dates
}
  
getQs(StartDate = CurrentDate, QuartersBack = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The yearqtr class represents years and quarters as years plus fractions 0, 1/4, 1/2 and 3/4 so given a date this gives the prior 3 quarters as yearqtr objects.  Below we used May 18, 2022 as the input and that corresponds to 2022 Q2.

If you want to convert that to the first or last date of the quarter as a Date object use `as.Date(...)` for the start or `as.Date(..., frac = 1)` for the end.  If you want to convert them to character use `format(...)`.  See `?format.yearqtr`.

```
library(zoo)

input <- as.Date("2022-05-18")
as.yearqtr(input) - 1:3/4
## [1] "2022 Q1" "2021 Q4" "2021 Q3"
```